# Laravel, how to find duplicated value between 2 arrays with different keys?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have 3 arrays, how do I return 'true' if the 2 array have the exact same value? In this case, $array1 and $array2 is true meanwhile $array1 and $array3 is 'false' because one of the value is not same. Is there an eloquent way to do this?

```
$array1 = array('dog'=>1, 'cat'=>2, 'monkey'=>3);
$array2 = array('red'=>1, 'green'=>2, 'blue'=>3);
$array3 = array('desk'=>1, 'chair'=>2, 'carpet'=>2);
```

Comment: Your question is tagged with `Laravel`, and you ask for an `eloquent` way - do you mean using Laravel's collections?

Comment: if laravel have alternative way, yes

Comment: OK, I added an answer doing it with Laravel, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see [Array operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

```
$arraysAreEqual = ($a == $b); // TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.
$arraysAreEqual = ($a === $b); // TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.
```

The inequality operator is `!=` while the non-identity operator is `!==` to match the equality operator  == and the identity operator `===`.

---

As an alternative, you can use `implode()` and check if the strings are equal, method 2:

```
if(implode('', $array1) === implode('', $array2)) {
    echo "Equal";
}
```

**EDIT BY OP**
the final answer

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value) 
{ 
  foreach($array2 as $key1 => $value1) 
  { 
    if(implode('', $array1[$key]) === implode('', $array2[$key1])) 
    { 
      echo "EQUAL"; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: i tried using method 2...have an error "Array to string conversion"

Comment: Here is a working code: https://3v4l.org/iHs21 May be, you are using `print` instead of `print_r` and hence you are getting the error.

Comment: can we enter a chat room so that it is easier to solve this prob?

Comment: Yes, we can but I don't think we can directly start a chat room, unless you have access.

Comment: last time u answered my questions and u invited me to a chat room

Comment: Well, stackOverflow provides that option, if there are too many comments on a single question / answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151823/discussion-between-milan-chheda-and-begineeeerrrr).

Answer (score 3):

```
function compare($arrayX, $arrayY) {
    return array_values($arrayX) == array_values($arrayY)
}

compare($array1, $array2) // TRUE
compare($array1, $array3) // FALSE
```

[array_values](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-values.php) will return you all values of the array in an array.

Comment: appreciate the answer, i cant find the documentation for compare()...could you lead me there?

Comment: There is no official `compare`function, I just wrote to minimize the code. It's no Laravel function, but the fastest way to do it.

Comment: oh sorry about that...i think i will try your codes...can you enter this discussion earlier that i made with other guy...inside i have shown my array...https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151823/discussion-between-milan-chheda-and-begineeeerrrr

Answer (score 1):

@mimo's solution is a great way to do it with plain arrays.  However you explicitly asked for a Laravel solution, so here you go:

```
function areSame($a1, $a2) {
    return collect($a1)->diff(collect($a2))->count() === 0;
}
```

This simply creates collections of the input arrays, so we can use Laravel's collection methods on them.  Then find the differences between the input collections - if there are differences, this will result in a collection of X items.  If there are no differences, the resulting diff collection will be empty.

```
areSame($array1, $array2) // TRUE
areSame($array1, $array3) // FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try extracting the values from the arrays using `array_values` and then comparing them like

```
$array1 = array('dog'=>1, 'cat'=>2, 'monkey'=>3);
$array1v = array_values($array1);
$array2 = array('red'=>1, 'green'=>2, 'blue'=>3);
$array2v = array_values($array2);
$array3 = array('desk'=>1, 'chair'=>2, 'carpet'=>2);
$array3v = array_values($array3);
```

and then

```
$array1v == $array2v; //true
$array1v == $array3v; //false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_diff` function. Like this:

```
$array1 = array('dog'=>1, 'cat'=>2, 'monkey'=>3);
$array2 = array('red'=>1, 'green'=>2, 'blue'=>3);
$array3 = array('desk'=>1, 'chair'=>2, 'carpet'=>2);

if (count(array_diff($array1, $array2)) > 0) {
    echo 'false';
} else {
    echo 'true';
}
```

And in this example `$array1` and `$array2` is true; `$array1` and `$array3` is false.

Comment: even though the key is different?

Answer (score 0):

checkout this :

```
function compare($arr1 , $arr2)
{
  return array_values($arr1) == array_values($arr2); 
}

$anyTowArraysAreEquals = compare($array1 , $array2) || compare($array1 , $array3) || compare($array2 , $array3);
```